# How can I get a string as a Type object?

Tags: c#, .net

What I want to achieve is this:

```
string myClass;
Type type=myClass.ConvertToType()
var object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<type>(something);
```

Is there a function like ConvertToType() ? or is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetType_System_String_) should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get the assembly the type is in.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

or

```
var assembly = typeof(anyTypeThatIsInTheAssembly).Assembly;
```

Then, you get your type that way:

```
var type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
```

Finally, you can deserialize the object with this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(something, type);
```

Comment: It kind of works how I want it to so thanks! But there's another problem. I want to cast the deserialized object to a class and it gives me this error:System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Templates.Template'.'Is this something about the assembly or type? Or is it just the JsonConverter? I also tryed using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<typeof(typeVariable)>(something) but it says that I'm using it as a type when it's a variable

Comment: Generic types/methods (where you set the type inside <>) must have the generic type known at compile time (unless you use compiled expression but that's another subject).
To cast you object to the desired type (if the cast is possible), then cast it in `object`before: `var result = (DesiredType)(object)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(something, type);`